# Whats wrong here? (TCP server/client, cross thread fields, encoding)

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, networking, encoding

I tried making an incredibly simple test project to feel my way around vb.net tcp/ip stuff. Even though its not relevant to my final goal with the thing, I'd like to figure out why this thing isn't working like predicted.

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Threading
Public Class Form1
    Public listener As New TcpListener(50000)
    Public outClient As New TcpClient
    Public outStream As NetworkStream

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        listener.Start()
        Dim t As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf listenersub)
        t.Start()

        outClient.Connect(New IPAddress({127, 0, 0, 1}), 50000)
        outStream = outClient.GetStream
    End Sub

    Public inClient As TcpClient
    Public inStream As NetworkStream
    Private Sub listenersub()
        inClient = listener.AcceptTcpClient
        inStream = inClient.GetStream
        Dim inBuffer(inClient.ReceiveBufferSize - 1) As Byte

        tbWrite("connected")

        While True
            If inClient.Available >= 22 Then
                inStream.Read(inBuffer, 0, inClient.ReceiveBufferSize)
                tbWrite(System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetString(inBuffer))
            End If

            Thread.Sleep(1)
        End While
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim b() As Byte = System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes("Hello there")
        outStream.Write(b, 0, b.Count)
    End Sub


    Public WithEvents tbTimer As New Windows.Forms.Timer() With {.Enabled = True, .Interval = 100}
    Public tbText As String = ""
    Public tiText As String = ""
    Public Sub tbWriter() Handles tbTimer.Tick
        TextBox1.Text = tbText
        Me.Text = tiText
    End Sub
    Public Sub tbWrite(s As String)
        SyncLock tbText
            tbText = s & vbNewLine & tbText
        End SyncLock
    End Sub
    Public Sub tiWrite(s As String)
        SyncLock tiText
            tiText = s
        End SyncLock
    End Sub
End Class
```

On the designer side, there should be a multiline textbox named textbox1 and a button "button2". What I expected to happen was for a new line of "Hello there" appear in the textbox whenever i push button 2, what actually happens is that i get "Hello there" but just one line. I cant figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when trying to telnet to devices.
The way out is to replace "0" in the byte stream and then provide it to GetString

This is what i had done

```
 Dim tcp_bytes As UInt32 = rtr_w.Read(tcp_data, 0, tcp_data.Length)
 If tcp_data.Contains(0) Then
    For j As UInt16 = 0 To tcp_bytes - 1
          'converting 0 to 32 to avoid line termination issues
      If tcp_data(j) = 0 Then tcp_data(j) = 32
    Next
 end if
```